# Prove that ${n\choose m} < \frac{n^n}{(m^m )(n-m)^{n-m}}$

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that $${n\choose m} < \frac{n^n}{(m^m )(n-m)^{n-m}}$$ I am stuck with this question guys. İt seems so easy because $ a!> b!+c!$ always if $b+c=a$ but I can not use this this fact to prove this question. Maybe there is another method.

Thanks for any help, maybe hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the binomial theorem to get
$$
n^n = (m+(n-m))^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} m^k (n-m)^{n-k}.
$$
Thus,
$$
n^n > {n \choose k} m^k (n-m)^{n-k}
$$
for all $k=0,1,\dots,n.$ Now apply this to $k=m$ to get the desired inequality.